# How to pass value from ng-click to ng-model?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, search, scope

In a foreign language dictionary app that I am working on I have a filter that uses a regular expression to turn each word in the search results into a URL that I would like the users to be able to click on and run a new search.

For example:

```
<a href ng-click="wordmatch($1)">$1</a>
```

`wordmatch()` is the function that performs the search, and `$1` is the value of the word or string in the search results that I would like to perform a new search on.

I need help passing the value of `wordmatch($1)` to my search or `ng-model="search.word"`.

I'm assuming this is an issue with `$scope`, but I'm new to Angular and I'm running out of ideas.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/w4Zd6mOsj3OuKWssEQXQ)

NOTE: For testing purposes I only have 40 words or so in my `data.json` file, so not all searches will yield a result.  Aale or eels will work.

Comment: It seems to me that the filter appends the new html to the existing already compiled dom, that is why, click is not actually binded to the scope function you have in controller. I would change the html to have there the <a> tag (angularjs supports filtering by regex) and so the ng-click should work. Also add href="#" to avoid refreshing the page
And the   <div ng-repeat="word in words | filter:wordmatch">  should be   <div ng-repeat="word in words | filter:search.word">

Comment: Additional explanation:
the div should filter based on the search.word because f you debug your code you can see that wordmatch function is called not at the right time.

Comment: Thanks Diana.  What are you suggesting I should do to the <a> tag?  I didn't quite understand.  Good catch on the href="#"!   Regarding changing the filter to "filter:search.word", when I do that the data or words in my json file are displayed without there being any search criteria typed into the search box, and I only like to display results if a search is being executed.  Thanks again for your suggestions!  Much appreciated!.

Comment: I was suggesting to have <a> tag in the html not in the angularjs filter. With the matchword filter, just debug and have  abreakpoint inside this function, you will see how many times it is called - basically for each word thatmatches the search. Rather try to think of a way to avoid filtering if search.word is empty instead of calling the filter and than this matchword function. This can have big performance impact when there will be not only 40 words, but 4k words, it will mean that you will execute 4k times the filter +4k times the matchword function.

Comment: I see now.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Any input you set ng-model on will automatically be bound to! So in your plunker, the search.word gets updated each time you type in the input. So if you have

```
Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search.word" placeholder="Search">
<a href ng-click="wordmatch(search.word)">$1</a>
```

in your wordmatch function, it will automatically see the value of $scope.search.word

Comment: Hi Jesse- thank you for your time and your response.  I tried adding  (search.word) to the href, but it didn't work. Each link for each word in each search result is different, so the value that is passed to wordmatch would have to be different too in order to run a new search on the selected word.  I believe that is why (search.word doesn't work..?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your demo you probably want to replace the `wordmatch($1)` with a function that updates the value of `$scope.search.word` so that the input text and result set is updated.

The other thing to be careful of is `$scope` inheritance. I love AngularJS but the `$scope` inheritance can be a mess. In most cases I prefer using the `controller as` method so it's always obvious where you are getting the data/methods from:

[AngularJS Controller documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

> Two different declaration styles are included below:
>
> - one binds methods and properties directly onto the controller using `this`: `ng-controller="SettingsController1 as settings"`
> - one injects `$scope` into the controller: `ng-controller="SettingsController2"`
>
> The second option is more common in the Angular community, and is generally used in boilerplates and in this guide. *However, there are advantages to binding properties directly to the controller and avoiding scope*.
>
> - Using `controller as` makes it obvious which controller you are accessing in the template when multiple controllers apply to an element.
> - If you are writing your controllers as classes you have easier access to the properties and methods, which will appear on the scope, from inside the controller code.
> - Since there is always a `.` in the bindings, you don't have to worry about prototypal inheritance masking primitives.

More details on `controller as` in this article: [Digging into Angular’s “Controller as” syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Comment: Hi Cory- thank you very much for taking the time to respond.  I will definitely check out the suggested links that you posted!  Hopefully I can find something to help me figure this out.  Thanks again!